# What is base.Update(gameTime) for in XNA games?

Tags: xna

It just occurred to me that I don't know what `base.Update(gameTime)` is supposed to do in the end of each XNA game project's `protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)` method.

I tried removing it and nothing broke. My guess is it may be used to update `GameService` stuff, which I don't use anyway. But what's it really for? Can removing it save some resources?

There is also `base.Draw(gameTime)` in the end of `protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)`. I wonder if these two are used for when the Game class inherits another Game class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are used for when you register a [GameComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx).

> A registered component will have its draw, update, and initialize methods called from the Game.Initialize, Game.Update, and Game.Draw methods.